# Optimizing complex types in the python function

Tags: python, mypy

I have a python function,

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_indexes(
    X: pd.DataFrame,
    y: pd.Series,
) -> (
    list[tuple[str | int, tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]]
    | list[tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]
):
    """Create indexes to train an estimator.
    
    This function takes a DataFrame and a Series and returns a list of
    tuples. Each tuple contains the name of the index and a tuple of
    arrays. The first array contains the indexes to train the estimator
    and the second array contains the indexes to test the estimator.

    Args:
        X (pd.DataFrame): The DataFrame containing the features.
        y (pd.Series): The Series containing the target.
    
    Returns:
        list[tuple[str | int, tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]]
        | list[tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]: The list of tuples.
    """
    pass
```

that returns complex types. How can I simplify this complex structure into better way? Ex. `list[fold, [train_indexes, test_index]]` in a wrapper or something else and, creating a separate file and call them in many functions when they need.

Note:- I do not want to use pydantic to validate them, but, writing this hint to make sure that others can also understand while reading a code.

I have no idea how to simplify this complex structure.

Comment: How about `list[tuple[int | str | None, np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]`?

Comment: Extract aliases, e.g. `ItemA: TypeAlias = tuple[str | int, tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]` and `ItemB: TypeAlias = tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]`, then `-> list[ItemA] | list[ItemB]`. (of course, name them appropriately to convey some meaning)

Comment: @STerliakov Thank you for saving my time. Your approach is more useful and I will follow it.